# Is possible to setting a color into JTree?

Tags: java, jframe, jtree

I created a tree but i'm unaware of setting color to it.

```
    JTree tree;
    JList list;
    JFrame frame;
    tree=new JTree("Tree");
    frame.add(tree,BorderLayout.WEST);
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
    frame.add(teamMember,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(list,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Is possible to set color in JTree?

Comment: Setting color to Tree node for JTree

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The colors (both foreground and background) for your tree nodes come from the `TreeCellRenderer` that is associated with your `JTree`.  The tree cell renderer for your `JTree` depends on the look and feel, but you can probably assume that it is descended from `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`.  If it is, then you can call several color-setting methods on `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` to change the colors of your tree, like this:

```
tree = new JTree(root);
if (tree.getCellRenderer() instanceof DefaultTreeCellRenderer)
{
    final DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = 
        (DefaultTreeCellRenderer)(tree.getCellRenderer());
    renderer.setBackgroundNonSelectionColor(Color.YELLOW);
    renderer.setBackgroundSelectionColor(Color.ORANGE);
    renderer.setTextNonSelectionColor(Color.RED);
    renderer.setTextSelectionColor(Color.BLUE);
}
else
{
    System.err.println("Sorry, no special colors today.");
}
```

Comment: Note that executing this sample code may hurt your eyes due to all of the clashing yellow, orange, and red colors. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

`JTree` inherits color methods from `JComponent`, e.g. `setBackground`. See for example [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29)

Comment: `setBackground` sets the background color of the tree, but not the one of the cells. The text of the node therefore still appears whith a white background.